# Magento Shipping Method

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, shipping-methods, http-request

I have created a custom shipping method in Magento but my question how i can call a request from external gateway and read XML data in Magento shipping method .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code in your shipping module.

Use curl to get data from external url

```
//Initialise curl object
$ch = curl_init();

//Define curl options in an array
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => "your-external-url",        
    CURLOPT_HEADER => "Content-Type:application/xml",        
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
);

//Set options against curl object
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

//Assign execution of curl object to a variable
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Close curl object
curl_close($ch);

//Pass results to the SimpleXMLElement function
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

print_r($xml);
```

Comment: I got this error `String could not be parsed as XML`.

Comment: The most likely cause of this error is that the XML data you are trying to process is not valid. Alternatively, the XML data may contain non-standard characters or use a different character set encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more details about Magento 2 shipping method just visit our [Magento 2 Shipping Methods](https://www.mconnectmedia.com/shipping-and-payment-method-per-customer-group-for-magento-2.html)